# Memory allocation for request and session object in java? Any Difference between them?

Tags: java

We know JVM allocates memory for objects from Heap Space but the question is How the memory for request and session object is allocated and who allocates memory for these objects,JVM or web server(tomcat or something else)? and any difference in memory allocation between these two objects? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Webservers run under JVM and JVM does dat job. Object wise there is no difference but differnce would be in object scope.

Answer (score 3):

Just like any other object , Session is also a Java Object. When web server requests JVM to create a Seesion object, JVM allocates memory for it.

Comment: I would say the web server asks the JVM to allocate memory for it to make it clear that the JVM doesn't do this on it's own.

Comment: @PeterLawrey So my webserver's JVM and the application's (my www..xyz.com war) JVM are different ? I'm in a impression that they both are on the single JVM. Wrong?

Comment: Each web server can create a different Session object.  These objects are just plain objects but their name, code and fields can be  different.  If you have a core Java program, there might not be a session object or anything like,  there is nothing in the JVM which suggests there has to be one, it is only due to the fact you have a web service, that it is creating one at all.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks. Clarified with second comment and added more words to my answer.

Comment: I got clear idea from all of your conversion over here... thank u all for your valuable time...